# how to add column in rdlc which shows once in one record

Tags: c#, rdlc

I have columns in dataset which are

> empcode, empname, earning, dedution, sal, amount, department

it shows like:

```
earning              sal                    dedution                   amount
a                     10                      b                          200
c                     30
```

but I want that it also show department and name on every page but only one time like:

```
empname   rajbir    department    sale

earning              sal                    dedution                   amount
a                     10                      b                          200
c                     30
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add [Group](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251700%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) on the page.

**Edit:**
Group the data based on empName and departmentName.

See the [link](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/83092c3c-60a2-4dbf-af26-60e1dcb8ed20/how-to-use-group-by-in-rdlc-i-have-to-group-by-date?forum=sqlreportingservices)

[image]

Here I added a group ContractorName and merged the cells.

Comment: but on next page the employee name goes same on first page

Comment: There may be some other problem.Can you describe the problem

Comment: Hi, could you please expand on this answer?

Comment: 0 Points

7 Posts


here I given more detailed explanation of what I need. The report shd display for each vendor

 

PAGE1

[Header]

Company Name

Address1

Address2

 

Vendor Name : Vendor1
 

[Order Number]

Vendor Address
 

 

 
 

Page : 1

Item
 

Unit Price
 

Quantity
 

Price

Item1
 

10
 

5
 

50.00

Item2
 

25
 

4
 

100.00

 

[footer]

 

PAGE2

[Header]

Company Name

Address1

Address2

 

 
 

Page : 2

Item
 

Unit Price
 

Quantity
 

Price

Item3
 

2
 

5
 

10.00

Item4
 

7
 

4
 

28.00

Total
 

188.00

 

Prepared by :  [Employee Name]